# Looking for BLE peripheral dongle for Windows IoT core with Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I am developing a UWP project to run on Raspberry Pi 3b that will advertise a Gatt Server. I based my program on the 3rd scenario in the windows IoT samples provided by Microsoft. I am using unpaired communication. Initially using the on-board BLE of the raspberry pi I get BSOD/restarts.

I narrowed the problem and suspected that it happens when:

- client is not disconnected properly, i.e. android device is not disconnected properly
- i try to notify using IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList> NotifyValueAsync(IBuffer value) on all devices even on devices not properly disconnected.

I did find on Microsoft documentation that it only supports low bandwidth devices so I limited my mtu/packet size, and added intervals on notification.

To fix the crash issue, I added a check for session status before sending notification to each individual subscribers. This seem to solve my issue on the crash. it hasn't happened again on my recent test. I am using 10.0.17763.1397 so maybe they also have some fix.

```
 foreach (var client in characteristic.SubscribedClients)

{

    try{

         if (client.Session.SessionStatus == GattSessionStatus.Active)

        {
              GattClientNotificationResult result = await characteristic.NotifyValueAsync(data.AsBuffer(), client);

        }

    }

    catch(Exception ex)

    {

    //if client is not disconnected properly, like
    // bluetooth in client is turned off or becomes out of 
    //range it throws and error that on client.Session.SessionStatus

    }

}
```

I also restart the GATT server every 60 seconds, like stopping the advertising and creating/restarting it again every 60 seconds if no client is subscribed/connected.

Now my problem is if I try to cycle scanning-connecting-reading, after some tries (6-20 tries) my client stops detecting the device. Only rebooting the device could solve the issue as I already tried restarting radio from my app and from powershell (using devcon). It didn't solve the issue.

Since I needed a perfect stable solution. I am opting to use BLE dongle with peripheral mode. I did see suggested BLE dongles from (I couldn't reply because it was already archived).

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/344fc709-7e13-499a-94ee-3c935ad503bb/ble-gatt-server?forum=WindowsIoT

but I was hoping for some proof of concept before I buy them. (I did buy a bunch of CSR BLE dongles from hardware compatibility list of microsoft but none of them work)

If anyone have already tested:

- BLE-USB-CR (RoHS)
- BT900-US Laird

Please let me know your thoughts and how you made it work. I also saw the Bluefruit LE Friend from Adafruit but I'm not sure if it is compatible with Windows IOT.

Suggestions on my current imperfect solution are also most welcome.

Comment: Is there any exception thrown when the client detecting the device?In addtion, did you stop advertising before your per cycle?

Comment: on my cycle scanning-connecting-reading, i dont stop the advertising (from gatt server side) unless the gatt server is restarting at same time i am scanning. I notice it actually breaks after the mobile device is already connected and attempting to subscribe on the services on the gatt server. when it breaks, the mobile device appears to be still connected but the gatt service it is not detected anymore. there is no exception thrown on the gatt server.

Comment: You may try to stop advertising before your cycle scanning-connecting-reading.